# Rotate a vector by a randomly oriented angle

Tags: geometry, random-sampling

We start off with a unit vector $\mathbf{v}$ randomly oriented in 3D space and we want to generate another unit vector $\mathbf{w}$ so that

$$ \mathbf{w}\cdot \mathbf{v} = \cos \beta $$

where $\beta$ is a given fixed angle. The new vector $\mathbf{w}$ must be randomly oriented, so that on average the cross product

$$ \langle \mathbf{w}\times \mathbf{v} \rangle = 0 $$

Normalization is $|\mathbf{v}|^2 = |\mathbf{w}|^2 = 1 $

How would you generate a particular vector $\mathbf{w}$ which satisfies the above conditions, using only 1 random number, and requiring as little computations as possible?

I have a "dirty" solution using polar coordinates, where I use an orthonormal set of vectors

$$
\mathbf{v} = \begin{pmatrix}
\sin \theta \cos \phi\\
\sin \theta \sin \phi\\
\cos \theta
\end{pmatrix} \quad 
\mathbf{v}^* = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta \cos \phi\\
\cos \theta \sin \phi\\
-\sin \theta
\end{pmatrix} \quad 
\mathbf{v}^{\dagger} = \begin{pmatrix}
-\sin \phi\\
\cos \phi\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

or, in Cartesian components

$$
\mathbf{v} = \begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix} \quad 
\mathbf{v}^* = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\begin{pmatrix}
xz\\
yz\\
z^2-1
\end{pmatrix} \quad 
\mathbf{v}^{\dagger} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} \begin{pmatrix}
-y\\
x\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The random orientation is then selected by a linear superposition
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{v}^* \cos(2\pi \alpha) + \mathbf{v}^{\dagger} \sin(2\pi \alpha)
\end{equation}
where $\alpha \in (0,1)$ is a random number drawn from a uniform distribution. The rotation is given simply by

$$ \mathbf{w} = \mathbf{v}\cos \beta + \mathbf{a}\sin \beta $$

Mathematically this seems perfect, except in the situation where $z=1$ or close to it. Also, if I just keep rotating my vector, the normalization drifts away from 1 due to roundoff errors.

Do you have some ideas on a more general formula which would be numerically robust and maintain normalization more rigorously, preferably with not too many computations?

Answer (score 3):

First, set up an orthonormal coordinate system $\{ \hat{\bf x}, \hat{\bf y}, {\bf v} \}$ with ${\bf v}$ as one axis. Pick any random vector ${\bf a}$ which is not collinear with ${\bf v}$. Then either choice of unit vector
$$\hat{\bf x} := \frac{{\bf a} \times {\bf v}}{|{\bf a} \times {\bf v}|} \quad \text{or} \quad \hat{\bf x} := \frac{{\bf a} - ({\bf a} \cdot {\bf v}) {\bf v}}{|{\bf a} - ({\bf a} \cdot {\bf v}) {\bf v}|}$$
will be orthogonal to ${\bf v}$. $\hat{\bf y} := {\bf v} \times \hat{\bf x}$ completes the orthonormal coordinate frame. Now you can simply use spherical coordinates with ${\bf v}$ as the axis that is usually denoted as the $z$-axis: just let
$${\bf w} = \sin \beta \cos \phi\, \hat{\bf x} + \sin \beta \sin \phi\, \hat{\bf y} + \cos \beta\, {\bf v},$$
where $\alpha$ is drawn uniformly from $[0,2 \pi)$.

Comment: Very nice. When you have to generate lots of these vectors, this method greatly simplifies the calculation as you can precompute most of it. I may have a go comparing my original implementation against this one for speed comparison...

Comment: One improvement I would like to suggest: don't pick a "random" vector $\mathbf{a}$ - instead, choose one of `[1 0 0], [0 1 0], [0 0 1]` by looking at which of the coefficients of $\mathbf{v}$ is smallest: that gives you a "mostly orthogonal" first guess, and ensures that the cross product $\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{v}$ is well conditioned.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a single random number, you first need to find "a" solution (one vector w that meets the criterion), then rotate that vector about $\mathbf{v}$ by a randomly generated angle.

We have some flexibility when finding that first vector $w_0$ - we just need to find "a" vector at right angles to $v$ and rotate about that axis by $\beta$. We can choose any vector that is not $v$ and take the cross product with $v$ to get a vector that is at right angles. The general equation for rotating about a vector by an angle is given by the [Rodriguez formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) - if we are rotating about one of the unit axes, that simplifies considerably and allows you to get the initial vector.

Rotating that initial vector about $\mathbf{v}$ is going to take a bit of work. It might be convenient to use the formulation given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Quaternion-derived_rotation_matrix) which uses quaternions to simplify the calculation of the rotation matrix. It means that you have to first express the rotation about the axis as a quaternion (where $\phi$ is a randomly generated angle between 0 and $2\pi$):

$$q = \begin{bmatrix}{
q_r\\
q_i\\
q_j\\
q_k}
\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}{
\cos\frac{\phi}{2}\\
v_1 \sin{\frac{\phi}{2}}\\
v_2 \sin{\frac{\phi}{2}}\\
v_3 \sin{\frac{\phi}{2}}}
\end{bmatrix}$$

After which you define the rotation as

$$\mathbf{R} = \begin{bmatrix}
1-2s(q_j^2+q_k^2) & 2s(q_i q_j - q_k q_r) & 2s(q_i q_k + q_j q_r)\\
2s(q_i q_j + q_k q_r) & 1 - 2s(q_i^2 + q_k^2) & 2s(q_j q_k - q_i q_r)\\
2s(q_i q_k - q_j q_r) & 2s(q_j q_k + q_i q_r) & 1 - 2s(q_i^2 + q_j^2)
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $s=1$ if you constructed your quaternion to have unit length (more generally, $s = ||\mathbf{q}||^{-2}$).

Computationally, a lot of terms appear in pairs so you only need to do the multiplication once.

It's possible there is a clever shortcut - but I don't know of one.

### Update

I decided to see if I could implement the above in a piece of C code, and the result is here. No warranties that this is bug free, but some simple testing suggested it is "mostly correct". Might be a good starting point (note - in latest edit I made some changes to the calculation of w0 as the original was wrong...)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define TWOPI (4*acos(0))
#define NUM 1000000

float normalize(float *a) {
// normalize the vector given
  float temp = sqrt(a[0]*a[0]+a[1]*a[1]+a[2]*a[2]);
  for(int ii=0; ii<3; ii++) a[ii]/=temp;
  return temp;
}

void cross(float *a, float *b, float *c) {
// return cross product of a and b in c
  c[0] = a[1]*b[2] - b[1]*a[2];
  c[1] = a[2]*b[0] - a[0]*b[2];
  c[2] = a[0]*b[1] - a[1]*b[0];
  return;
}

float dot(float *a, float *b) {
  float sum=0;
  for(int ii=0; ii<3; ii++) sum+=a[ii]*b[ii];
  return sum;
}

void printmat(float r[][3]) {
  for(int ii=0; ii<3; ii++) {
    for(int jj=0; jj<3; jj++) {
      printf("%.4f\t", r[ii][jj]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n");
  return;
}

void printquat(float q[]) {
  for(int ii=0; ii<4; ii++) printf("%.4f\n", q[ii]);
  printf("\n");
  return;
}

void rotvec(float *axis, float *vec, float angle, float* result) {
// rotate vec about axis by angle
// return result
  float q[4]; // quaternion representation of vector
  float R[3][3]; // rotation matrix
  float s = sin(angle/2), c = cos(angle/2);
  // construct quaternion:
  q[0] = c;
  for(int ii=0; ii<3; ii++) q[ii+1]=axis[ii]*s;

  #ifdef VERBOSE
    printf("quaternion:\n");
    printquat(q);
  #endif
  // construct rotation matrix:
  float qii, qij, qik, qir, qjj, qjk, qjr, qkk, qkr;
  qii=q[1]*q[1]; qij=q[1]*q[2]; qik=q[1]*q[3]; qir=q[1]*q[0];
  qjj=q[2]*q[2]; qjk=q[2]*q[3]; qjr=q[2]*q[0];
  qkk=q[3]*q[3]; qkr=q[3]*q[0];
  R[0][0]=1-2*(qjj+qkk);
  R[0][1]=2*(qij-qkr);
  R[0][2]=2*(qik+qjr);
  R[1][0]=2*(qij+qkr);
  R[1][1]=1-2*(qii+qkk);
  R[1][2]=2*(qjk-qir);
  R[2][0]=2*(qij-qjr);
  R[2][1]=2*(qjk+qir);
  R[2][2]=1-2*(qii+qjj);

  #ifdef VERBOSE
    printf("rotation matrix: \n");
    printmat(R);
  #endif

  for(int ii=0; ii<3; ii++) {
    result[ii]=0;
    for(int jj=0; jj<3; jj++) {
      result[ii]+=R[ii][jj]*vec[jj];
    }
  }
  return;
}

void printvec(float *v) {
  for(int ii=0; ii<3; ii++) printf("%f\n", v[ii]);
  printf("\n");
  return;
}


void findw0(float *v, float b, float *w0) {
  // find any vector that has an angle b with vector v
  int mi=0;
  float minax=fabs(v[0]);
  for(int ii=1; ii<3; ii++) {
    if(fabs(v[ii])<minax) {
      mi=ii;
      minax = fabs(v[ii]);
    }
  }
  float X[]={0,0,0};
  X[mi]=1;
  float A[3]; // the axis we want to rotate about at right angles to v
  cross(v, X, A); // this finds "a" vector at right angles
  normalize(A); // make it unit length
  rotvec(A, v, b, w0); // rotate v about A by angle b
  return;
}

int main(void) {
// given an input vector v
// and an angle b
// find a random vector w that gives dot(v,w)=cos(b)

  float v[]={0,0,1};
  float b = acos(0)/2; // pi/4
  normalize(v);
  // find "a vector" w0 that has the right relationship:
  float w0[3];
  findw0(v, b, w0);
  printf("vector w0 that is pi/4 from Z axis:\n");
  printvec(w0);
  float w[3];
  float crossSum[]={0,0,0};
  float crossTemp[3];
  float bsum = 0;
  for(int ii=0; ii<NUM; ii++) {
    // generate random angle between -pi and pi:
    b = TWOPI*(rand()*1.0/RAND_MAX-0.5);
    bsum+=b;
    rotvec(v, w0, b, w);
    cross(v, w, crossTemp);
    for(int jj=0; jj<3; jj++) crossSum[jj]+=crossTemp[jj]/NUM;
  }
  printf("after %d iterations, mean cross product is\n", NUM);
  printvec(crossSum);
  printf("mean angle of rotation is %.3f\n", bsum/NUM);
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Find a vector $\vec a$ such that $\vec v \times \vec a \ne 0$. Define $\hat x = (\vec v\,\times \vec a)/||\vec v \times \vec a||$. By construction, $\hat x$ is a unit vector and is orthogonal to $\vec v$. Define $\hat y = \vec v \times \vec x$. The triple $(\hat v, \hat x, \hat y)$ form a right handed coordinate system.

Form a second coordinate system $(\hat v, \hat x', \hat y')$ by rotating about $\hat v$ by an angle $\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is drawn from $U(0,2\pi)$. Finally, form a third coordinate system $(\hat w, \hat x', \hat y'')$ by rotating about $\hat x'$ by the desired angle $\beta$. By construction, $\hat w$ is a unit vector and $\hat w \cdot \hat v = \cos \beta$. Thanks to the original random rotation about $\hat v$, $\langle \hat w \times \hat v \rangle = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $$\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{w} = v_1w_1 + v_2w_2 + v_3w_3 = \cos\beta$$ and $$ v_1^2 + v_2^2 + v_3^2 = 1\,.$$ Randomly generate one component of $\mathbf{v}$ and use the two equations above to solve for the other components. Does this work?

Comment: okay, but what is the distribution from which you would draw the new random component? It must be demonstrated that on average the cross product $\langle \mathbf{w} \times \mathbf{v} \rangle = 0$, i.e. the new vector is equally likely to fall anywhere on the cone at an angle $\beta$ to the old vector.

Comment: Why not [0,1]? This is a bijection. It should give you what you want.

Comment: The length of an individual component of $w$ (which is the randomly generated vector) does not follow a uniform distribution. This method won't work.

Comment: @Floris Yeah, you're right! This is so cool! Should it be sinusoidal?

Comment: I think $\cos(rand(-\pi/2,\pi/2))$ might get you part of the way; but you still need to decide on the sign of the other components or you will end up in just some quadrant - and that means generating more than one random number. I suppose that generating a random number between $-\pi$ and $\pi$ might suffice - you could then take the sine and the cosine to give you the two pieces you need. Maybe.